# Animation moves image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, cgaffinetransform

I am trying to create my first iPhone application. The application is simply a arrow pointing at north.
I have so far added a image of a arrow, and created a animation via the following code:

```
- (void)setDirection:(float)degree {
        float rad = M_PI * (float)degree / 180.0;
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:10];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
         //[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
        DirectionArrow.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rad);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
```

My problem is that the arrow "moves" before it rotates, each time I call the method. I have tried varius things to center the rotation angle, but without any luck.

I want the arrow (image) to rotate around its own axis.

Comment: Can you clarify 'the arrow "moves"'? Do you have any code that positions the arrow before you apply the rotation?

Comment: there are some solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232460/cgaffinetransformmakerotation-around-external-point

Comment: I have just added a Image directly to UIView. I dont have any other code then the rotation code.

Its hard to explain how it moves. When I call the rotate button the position of the image changes before it starts to rotate..

Answer (score 4):

This is because your view is rotating around `(0, 0)`, which is the top-left corner of your view. You'd want to rotate around the center of the arrow instead.

To do so, you'll have to build a transform that does the following:

1. Translates the arrow such that it's center is at `(0, 0)`.
2. Rotates the view in `rad` degrees.
3. Translates the arrow back (the inverse transform of (1)).

It should be something like (up to flip of t1 and t3):

```
CGFloat h = view.bounds.size.height;
CGFloat w = view.bounds.size.width;
CGAffineTransform t1 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-w/2, -h/2);
CGAffineTransform t2 = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rad);
CGAffineTransform t3 = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(w/2, h/2);
CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformConcat(t3, t2), t1);
DirectionArrow.transform = t;
```

Comment: In other words, you need to change the anchor point around which you rotate the arrow. +1

Comment: Thanks for the help.

To be sure that I understand this correctly, I need to put the Image into a separate view, move the arrow to position 0,0 in that view, rotate and move the arrow back ???

Is it still possible to see the rotation animation ?

Comment: You can put it in a separate view, or just translate to the center of the arrow (if it's currently not at the center of the view, you'll have to set a different `(x, y)` values for the translation. Regarding the animation, you'll see the arrow rotating correctly since basically what this does is to rotate around a different anchor point of `(x, y)` rather than the original `(0, 0)`.

Comment: Ok, i have tried for days now to make the rotationcenter of the animation. 

Do I need to configure some properties on the image in any specific way?  

I would really appreciate some help, as this simple task is killing me.

Comment: directionArrow.center = CGPointMake(0,0); Made is almost right. good enough that I can continue with other tasks, and get back to this when I have the time... Thanks for the suggestions.